# R: GLMM glmer vs glmmPQL

Tags: r, glm, lme4

What is the syntax in `glmmPQL` for multiple random effects?

With `glmer` my code looks like:

```
fit<- glmer(A~B+C+ (1 | D)+ (1 | E), family = gaussian, data=data)
```

how to rewrite the same exact thing using `glmmPQL`?

I was trying:

```
fit<- glmmPQL(A~B+C, random=c (~1 | D, ~1 | E), family = gaussian, data=data)
```

but it gives an error.

And what is the major difference between `glmer` and `glmmPQL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the example you provided, the model with `glmmPQL` would be specified as:

```
fit <- glmmPQL(A ~ B + C, random = list(D = ~1, E = ~1), family = gaussian, data = data)
```

AFAIK, the major difference between `glmer` (which is provided by the package `lme4`) and `glmmPQL` (which relies on function `lme`, from the `nlme` pacakge) is that the parameter estimation algorithm used in `nlme` is not optimized for dealing with crossed random effects, which are associated with a sparse design matrix, while `lme4` takes advantage of this structure; see, e.g., Pinheiro & Bates, "Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS", Springer, 2000, pp. 163. Further references on the differences between `lmer/glmer` and `lme` are the usual:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-October/115572.html

Answer (score 3):

> And what is the major difference between `glmer` and `glmmPQL`?

To add to [tguzella answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149097/5861244) then `glmmPQL` uses PQL which has some known bias issues whilst `glmer` uses a Laplace approximation or Gauss-Hermite quadrature which are better approximations. See [the comments here by Ben Bolker](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#what-methods-are-available-to-fit-estimate-glmms) and the papers cited therein. This may be a major downside for `glmmPQL` depending on the model you estimate and the data you have (e.g. it is not bad for large cluster in some cases).

The `glmer` function can however not fit certain types of correlation structures. See e.g., [the links](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison) in the aforementioned answer or [the comments on this page](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html).